# Runtime execution crash

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse

I have this problem in Eclipse, in Geany it seems it works ok...

```
void CopiaMaze( int MazeCopia[][COLUMNS])
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i < ROWS; i++){
        for(j=0; j < COLUMNS; j++){
            cout << "Fila Columna" << i <<j;
            MazeCopia[i][j] = m.getValueMap(i,j);
            cout << "Numero" << MazeCopia[i][j] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Im trying to copy an array of in this case rows 19 columns 40

The use is:

```
int inteligentMinimax(int jugador)
{

        int minimaxValue=0;
        int mazeTemp[ROWS][COLUMNS];

        fillCharacters();

        bestMovementPath.clear();

        CopiaMaze( mazeTemp);

        cout << "Paso Copia Maze";

        cout << "Characters:" << CharactersLocationsMaze;

        cout << "Minimax Value es: " << minimaxValue << "Depth :" << depth << "jugador:" << jugador;

        //Inicializo Minimax con los puntos del pacman a cero, direccion sin definir 0 y profunidad 10 que es variable global.
        minimaxValue = minimax(mazeTemp, 0, 0, depth, jugador);

        cout << "Minimax Value es: " << minimaxValue << "Direction :" << bestMovementPath[1];

        return bestMovementPath[1];
    }
```

so i enter in Copia Maze and the last results i get are:

```
Fila Columna1833Numero0
Fila Columna1834Numero0
Fila Columna1835Numero0
Fila Columna1836Numero0
Fila Columna1837Numero0
Fila Columna1838Numero0
Fila Columna1839Numero0
```

Where Numero 0 is the correct value get from m.getvaluemap(i,j)...

After this it should continue with cout Paso copiamaze,to show that i pass the copiamaze function... but it gets stuck and crashes.

Any help would be apreciated..

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with the code you have shown. The only help you need is help with writing a [mcve].

Comment: notice that your 3 `cout` between `CopiaMaze`call and `minimax` aren't flushed, your bug is most likely located in minimax then. You can flush cout via `endl` (with a newline as an effect) or with `flush`

Answer (score -1):

As @PW show i thought the problem was in CopiaMaze as the program crashed and it wouldn show the message "Paso Copia Maze", which was just a signal to notice if i passed CopiaMaze.

The problem is in Minimax code, and you can solve the issue just changing cout by cerr, and you can notice that the error come in minimax. Thats another thread though.

Thanks for your help.